# HIghchart Area Chart display NULL value in a wrong way

Tags: angularjs, highcharts

I have a series data like this [null,0,null,null,null,null,0.86,null,0,null]

As you can see, there are only three points in it.
However it has been displayed as below, 
[image]

Please see the [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/1qy8uz6L/) here,

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
chart: {
    type: 'area',
    spacingBottom: 30
},
title: {
    text: 'Fruit consumption *'
},


xAxis: {
    categories: ["Term 3_week1","Term 3_week2","Term 3_week3","Term 3_week4","Term 3_week5","Term 3_week6","Term 3_week7","Term 3_week8","Term 3_week9","Term 3_week10"]
},
yAxis: {
    title: {
        text: 'Y-Axis'
    }
},

plotOptions: {

    area: {
        fillOpacity: 0.5
    }
},
credits: {
    enabled: false
},
series: [{
    name: 'John',
    data: [null,0,null,null,null,null,0.86,null,0,null]
}]
```

});

I am quite confused why this been displayed like this.

Can anyone help?
Thanks

Comment: How do you want it to display?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First if you look your demo on firefox it will only show 3 points without any area.

Now you may try to use `connectNulls` [Api Doc](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.area.connectNulls) like that :

```
chart: {
    type: 'scatter',
    spacingBottom: 30
},
plotOptions: {
    area: {
        fillOpacity: 0.5,
        connectNulls:true
    }
},
```

**Edit**: New type of chart

[Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1qy8uz6L/6/)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer!
However, I only need three points not a connected area so how I can slove it?

Comment: @QingXu, then you should change the type for `scatter`. I updated my answer with the new chart type.